# Cannot find AddRefitClient method for Worker Service

Tags: .net, refit, worker-service

Currently I using .NET version 7 to do background job service. I add Worker Service project, in `Program.cs` file I cannot call method `AddRefitClient` although I add package `Refit` to call API. I don't want to use HttpClient

This is error message:

> `'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddRefitClient' and no accessible extension method 'AddRefitClient' accepting a first argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

[image]

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/11286032)

Answer (score 13):

You also need the package [Refit.HttpClientFactory](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Refit.HttpClientFactory) to install.

Comment: That was my issue, thanks